# How to change field input border color in odoo 16.0?

Tags: html, css, colors, odoo, odoo-16

In the 16th version of Odoo, for some reason, my input field became transparent.

It can be found if you know approximately where it is located and click on it with the mouse, and then only the lower border of the stroke of this field will appear:

[image: what does it look like now]

Unfortunately, I could not find options in Odoo 16 how to do this correctly.

My solution at the moment now looks like this, I painted over the form in a different color, and fill the color of the input fields with white, I don’t think this is the right option.

```
<form delete="false" default_order="name" style="background-color:#DDDDE4;">
    <field name="title" style="background-color:#ff0000;" placeholder="title"/>
    <field name="body" widget="html" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" placeholder="body"/>
</form>`
```

[image: what does my solution look like]

This is my temporary solution, but I'm not sure if it's correct.

Comment: Do you want these style changes for only one (or few) view or for the whole system?

Comment: For all, becouse they are so "crooked" everywhere

Comment: I generally consider this a problem, and perhaps you need to open a PR with a fix.
There was no such problem in odoo-15.

Comment: My suggestion is to simply imitate the style in Odoo community or to make the input field slightly darker than the white backdrop.

Comment: For Odoo themselves that's not a problem or bug, but a design decision. And i'm not happy about this either.

Comment: @CZoellner yes, is working, method is described below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Solution is
add a custom CSS file and override the field CSS

the best location for the custom CSS file
`module_name -> static -> src -> css -> css_file.css`

for example
add a border on input fields at the lower side the put css

```
.o_form_view .o_input {
    padding: 2px 4px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000 !important;
}
```

Note: this CSS is only for Char fields

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps someone will need it. It`s working for me.

**My page XML:**

```
<form delete="false" default_order="name">
    <field name="title"/>
</form>
```

**My page.py:**

```
from odoo import fields, models

class InfoPageSection(models.Model):
    _name = "my_module.page.section"
    title = fields.Char("Title", required=True, index=True)
```

**My **manifest**.py:**

```
'assets': {
        'web.assets_common': [
            ('prepend', 'my_module/static/src/css/mycss.css'),
        ], },
```